# MongoDB : Passing Python variables breaks the flow

Tags: python, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB but have a working piece of code:

```
min_hits = db.collection.find_one({"type": "min_hits"})["value"]
print min_hits
```

which prints:

```
100
```

Now I have to make use of this value in another MongoDB Query:

```
data =  db.collection.aggregate([{"$match":{"created_at":{"$gte":start,"$lt":end}}},{"$group":{"_id":"$stage","count":{"$sum":1}}},{"$match":{"count":{"$gt":min_hits}}}])
```

But it does not results any dataset however when I change to below query

```
data =  db.collection.aggregate([{"$match":{"created_at":{"$gte":start,"$lt":end}}},{"$group":{"_id":"$stage","count":{"$sum":1}}},{"$match":{"count":{"$gt":100}}}])
```

i.e. directly place a numeric value I get result as expected?

```
{u'count': 504, u'_id': u'111.111.111.111'} 
{u'count': 2941, u'_id': u'101.125.114.115'}
```

Why is that I do not get the result set when I pass min_hits variable than numeric value itself?

```
{"$match":{"count":{"$gt":min_hits}}} = no result set value of min_hits is 100
{"$match":{"count":{"$gt":100}}} = result set as required
```

Comment: What happens if you check `type(min_hits)`? Also I assume the `Adb` instead of `db` was a typo?

Comment: Thanks previously it was printing <type 'unicode'> - I type casted it to int and it worked fine. Thanks for the pointers . Yes Adb was a typo issue.
Changed the code as :
min_hits = int(db.collection.find_one({"type": "min_hits"})["value"]).